# Prepositional verbs: why don't we put proposition 'with' after some verbs?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I have the verb 'meet', and I mostly think that there should have been the preposition 'with', as in:

1. I meet **with** him.
2. I meet him.

Is first sentence appropriate? If so, then why is it appropriate to say like this:

1. The two **argued with each other** for several minutes.”

And, also, what are other verbs (after which most of learners think that there should have been the preposition) that don't need prepositions?“

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Meet](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/meet-and-meet-with)*** means both to encounter someone or something for the first time and to come together in order to talk. ***Meet with*** only means the latter when referring to people.

***[Meet with](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/meet_1)***  is generally used in more formal contexts:   *meet  by arrangement:*

> [intransitive, transitive, no passive] to come together formally in order to discuss something:
>
> The committee meets on Fridays.
>
> ***meet somebody***  World leaders are meeting in Paris next month for talks.
>
> ***meet with somebody***  The President met with senior White House aides.

(OLD)

From [Politics of Postal transformation:](https://books.google.it/books?id=etzMcbw1TWwC&pg=PR15&dq=%22i%20met%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLxuni06_cAhUCIpoKHaF7DvgQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=%22i%20met%20with%22&f=false)  2002

> Sheila Daout kindly organized my visit to the United States Postal Service. ***I met with Deborah Willhite,*** vice- president, Government Relations, and members of her team for an extended discussion.

Other usage examples of [meet with](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&safe=strict&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2001,cd_max:2008,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22%20I%20Met%20with%22&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie5LWy1K_cAhXDA5oKHSB7ACkQBQgiKAA&biw=768&bih=909&dpr=2)

Answer (score 2):

Transitive verbs such as *meet* in this context do not need a preposition before their object. So, *'I meet him for lunch'*, is sufficient.

In fact, including the unnecessary preposition is quite common in everyday communication. You will also hear: '*I meet up with him for lunch*'. Note, however, that such usage is frowned on in style guides such as *Garner's Modern American Usage* (628):

> Don't use a phrasal verb if the adverbial particle (preposition) is
>   simply baggage that doesn't add to meaning. Thus, don't say *meet up
>   with* if *meet* suffices. Don't say *connect up* or *divide up* if
>   *connect* and *divide* suffice.

But there is one context in which *'I meet with him'* is preferred. For example, if you have a predetermined meeting once a week, then using the preposition is the right choice:

As to your second question, *argue* is an intransitive verb in this context. Intransitive verbs cannot be followed directly by an object. So, the following is ungrammatical:

> *The two argued each other for several minutes.

You need the preposition *with*.

Comment: ‘Meet up with’ is an interesting example.  I think it arises from another informal expression:  “Let’s meet up some time”.  Then, when, when we do, the ‘up’ stays put and I ‘meet up with’ you and you ‘meet up with’ me.  There is, though, a sort of distinction.  To ‘meet with’ someone often (not always) means ‘hold a meeting’.  So, for example, I might promise to meet you at heathrow, not to ‘meet with you’, unless we are planning to spend time in the cafe or priority lounge having some sort of conversation, however informal.